# How to add blog in URL (Blog page, Taxonomy page and Single page ) with pagination using WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, clean-urls, url-slug

I want to this structure in default post type.

- Archive Page (Blog page) - `example.com/blog/`
- pagination link - `example.com/blog/page/2/`
- Taxonomy page - `example.com/blog/taxonomy-slug/`
- pagination link - `example.com/blog/taxonomy-slug/page/2/`
- Single page - `example.com/blog/post-title/`

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy creates usually duplicated content. So i would make taxonomy terms as parameters to easy deindex them. Like this:

- pagination link - domain.com/blog/page/2/
- taxonomy slug: pagination link - domain.com/blog/page/2/?taxonomy=term1
- Single page - domain.com/blog/posttitle/?taxonomy=term1
- Single page pagination - domain.com/blog/posttitle/page/2/?taxonomy=term1

Comment: yes this is working but there is no index and crawl this type URL in SEO standard.

Comment: don't understand, what you mean

Comment: Yes, This type URL working but effects on SEO rule.